# Getting different data from asp core web api through different networks

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

We wrote a web api for our Android application with ASP.NET Core. It works fine when we connect to the mobile data or any other Internet connection modem. But when we want to connect to the company's modem, it receives the wrong data from the host. For example, it displays the previous data on the database that we deleted, or it displays such and such data for someone.

Why does it happen and how can this be fixed?

Comment: Any proxy or cache server in between?

Comment: Yes, there is a microtik

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like that your Microtik caches responses. I don't know Mikrotic, but I suggest to add an exception to the cache proxy for your web api. See https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:IP/Proxy#Cache_Management

Additionally you could also add attributes to disable caching to your controller

```
[ResponseCache(Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
```